# Почему есть доступ к приватной переменной другого класса?

Tags: java, ооп, private

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    dog haski = new dog();
    haski.name = "sobaka";
    haski.age = 3;
    haski.info();
}

static class dog{
    String name;
    private int age;
    private void info(){
        System.out.println(name+"|"+age);
        }
}
```

Работаю в `intellij idea`. Выдаёт тройку, хотя вроде как нельзя обращаться к переменной напрямую, если она приватная. Не понимаю, в чём проблема?

Comment: У вас что этот код работает вообще?  Я не очень по джаве но разве можно создать экземпляр статического класса dog? По мне этот код вообще не рабочий.

Comment: Класс `dog` лежит внутри того класса, в котором находится `main()`. Поэтому из этого метода можно оперировать приватными полями и методами класса `dog`. Если бы он был отдельным самостоятельным классом, то конечно же мы бы не имели доступа к его приватным членам.

Comment: Byb спасибо, протупил

Answer (score -3, accepted):

вот верный код

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog haski = new Dog();
        haski.name = "sobaka";
        haski.setAge(3);
        haski.info();
    }
}

class Dog {
    String name;
    private int age;

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void info() {
        System.out.println(name + "|" + age);
    }
}
```

Comment: И как ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос "Почему есть доступ к приватной переменной другого класса?"?

Comment: Такой код действительно логичнее, чем код из вопроса, но автор-то спрашивал, почему есть доступ к переменной. К тому же, если вы предлагаете исправленный код, то рекомендуется объяснить, что было не так с кодом автора.

Comment: @Зонтик Я не знаю почему есть доступ к переменной. Я проверил в разных оболочках. Код не рабочий. К сожалению у меня нет intellij idea. Проверить на ней не могу. Либо автор привел не полный код либо что-то путает. В этом виде который привел автор доступа нет к приватной переменной. Я привел свой код исходя из кода автора максимально приближенным.  Класса "test" (который привели другие отвечавшие) у автора нет.

Comment: Но у автор есть класс, объявленный `static`, а такой класс может быть ***только*** вложенным.

Answer (score 1):

Код, приведённый в другом ответе, не является "правильным", равно как и код из вашего вопроса не является "неправильным".

В Java есть возможность объявлять классы внутри других классов. В отличие от внешних, такие классы могут иметь модификатор `static`. Который ни в коем случае не означает, что объект от данного класса не может быть создан, или что может быть создан только один объект этого класса. Их вполне можно создавать, и в каком угодно количестве.

```
public class Test {
    static class NestedClass {

    }

    class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test.NestedClass(); // работает
        new Test().new InnerClass(); // работает
        // new Test.InnerClass(); // ошибка! Объект от InnerClass не может быть создан отдельно от объекта класса Test
    }
}
```

Класс, находящийся в другом классе и являющийся `static`, называется *вложенным* (*nested*) классом.
Класс, находящийся в другом классе и не являющийся `static`, называется *внутренним* (*inner*) классом.

Разница между ними в том, что первый для создания объекта не требует объекта от своего обрамляющего класса, а второй - требует. Нельзя создать объект inner-класса отдельно от объекта обрамляющего класса.

Говорить, какой из них "правильный", а какой "неправильный" - некорректно, так как это просто совершенно разные классы с разным назначением.

Ну а касательно обращения к приватным членам я уже ответил в комментариях. Обрамляющий класс имеет доступ к приватным полям и методам находящихся в нём классов, будь они с модификатором `static` или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть класс, в котором находиться метод `main()`, будет называться `Test`. В общем, код на самом деле у вас выглядел так:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args){
         //Здесь вы создаёте объекты
    }

    static class Dog {
        //Поля и методы
    }

}
```

#### Что происходит в вашем коде

- У вас есть класс `Test`;
- **Внутри** класса `Test` есть класс `Dog`. Именно **внутри**. Ведь класс `Dog` в данном случае - *статический вложенный класс* (если на английском - то *static nested class*).
- Метод `main()` находиться внутри класса `Test`. А внешний класс (`Test`) имеет доступ ко всем полям вложенного (`Dog`), **в том числе и к приватным**. Вот и ответ на ваш вопрос. Кстати, сам статический вложенный класс имеет доступ **только к статическим** полям внешнего.

#### Как должен был выглядеть ваш код

В данном случае использовать статический вложенный класс не стоит. Лучше сделать класс `Dog` обычным (невложенным) классом. Почему? Потому что собака - отдельная сущность, никак не связанная с сущностью класса `Test`, и нет никаких других причин помещать класс `Dog` в класс `Test`.

Comment: Если вы ставите минус, то пожалуйста, напишите комментарий, что вам не нравиться в ответе, я его исправлю.

Comment: И если что, фраза из ответа `@Byb` ("Код, приведённый в другом ответе, не является "правильным" ") не про мой ответ, а про другой.